# Angularjs - resource won't post ISO-8859-1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iso-8859-1

I am trying to use an [Angularjs (1.4) resource](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/docs/api/ngResource/service/$resource) to post some json to a service. The post needs to be encoded as ISO-8859-1, so I have my resource set to pass headers:

```
    update: {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1',
            'From':'pohqlakt@sharklasers.com',
        }
    }, ...
```

I added the 'From' header just to verify that the headers are actually being passed. I am using Chrome's developer tools to check the post and I'm seeing the following:

```
    Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
    From:pohqlakt@sharklasers.com
```

I've gone over everything I can think of to find where 'UTF-8' is set. The page itself has the ISO charset configured:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
```

Does anyone know why it could be picking up UTF-8 and overriding the explicitly set ISO charset?

Comment: This is highly unusual. `XMLHttpRequest` uses `utf-8` by default and it is rare to ever need to change that. Would be better to set page to utf-8 also

Comment: Should the response be iso-8859-1? If so, that's gonna require some backend configuration. Else, maybe look for encoding along with the charset you are already setting?

Comment: Ultimately, I've got to put the post in a datastore that wants ISO-8859-1, and is supporting legacy systems that are not going to change.

Comment: Does the backend service require ISO-8859-1 request encoding? If it does not, encode to utf8, decode back to ISO-8859-1 on the backend and then store your data.

Comment: @RobertoNovelo - Yes, I have control of the service, so I could transcode before going to and coming from the database. I guess I might have to go that route.